# How to disable/block onClickListener for few seconds?

Tags: android, android-layout

I made nice looking splash screen and I want to block onclicklistener for a few seconds cause i've got few animations etc and I want the user see it all.

I've got:

```
 ostatni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                starttap.start();

                Intent i = new Intent(Start.this,ActivityMainWallet.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

## EDIT

I've got:

```
ostatni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                starttap.start();
                ostatni.setEnabled(false);


            }
        });

        wlot.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Start.this,ActivityMainWallet.class);

                startActivity(i);
                ostatni.setEnabled(true);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

And it doesn't work. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: you should set the onclicklistener when animation finishes

Comment: in `onClick` method you could do `ostatni.setOnClickListener(null)` and then set it again when the animation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pause the thread it is running on, the main thread (UI Thread):

`Thread.sleep(4000); // freeze the thread for 4 seconds`

Source: [Java, Pausing Execution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Answer (score 1):

`SystemClock.sleep(2000)`will be better.

sleep 2ms, and this method will not block the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use android animation utils to do this

```
final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.abc_fade_in);

<your imageviews or any other view>.startAnimation(an);
  an.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
     public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //start your main activity
     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this ?

```
public onCreate(....)
{
     ......
     ......
     ostatni.setOnClickListener(........);
     ostatni.setEnabled(false);
}

 @Override
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ostatni.setEnabled(true);
 }
```

Comment: @dawidurusek put your setEnabled(false) outside the onClickListener, otherwise it's can't be disabled when you're not click the button